# Book about a prince who becomes a captive then a mage - Asianesque

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

Would have been late 80s early 90s.  I got the boxed series as a gift for Christmas one year.

I remember it seeming very Asian in the theme of the characters. I think it was a prince who got captured and ultimately trained to be a mage/wizard.  What I really remember is, after he's captured, he can't remember who he is.  He lives in a cell and eats gruel every day with many other men/kids like himself.  He repeats a task over and over (filling something with a bucket of water that just keeps emptying?) until one day he has enough and refuses.  It's his refusal that leads them to start training him as a mage/wizard.

Comment: Kinda hints at Feist's [*Magician*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_(Feist_novel)), but only kinda.